# How can I add support for web workers in a CRACO Webpack application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, web-worker, craco

I want to leverage web workers in my react app. I decided to use [threads](https://threads.js.org/usage) as my supporting library.

For this to function with a webpack bundle [threads-plugin](https://github.com/andywer/threads-plugin) must be included. I happen to use [CRACO](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#configuration) and so I am still able to modify my webpack configuration.

Inside `craco.config.js` I add the plugin to my webpack object

```
webpack: {
        plugins: {
            add: [new ThreadsPlugin()]
        }
}
```

My worker is referenced as

```
const worker = new Worker('./workers/auth', { type: 'module' });
```

The error I am seeing on this line is

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Perhaps most notably, it appears to be trying to reference the worker as a URL instead of as a path within the bundled app.

```
:3000/workers/auth:1
```

Does this mean that `ThreadsPlugin` is not being bundled and utalized? What approaches can I take to gather more insight on the issue?

---

**EDIT**

I confirmed with logging that the `threads-plugin` library does get initialized by my webpack config. The larger portion of the library `WorkerPlugin.prototype.apply` does not seem to fire.

Exploring that I may have missed a step in the setup, asked the author. [More details here](https://github.com/andywer/threads-plugin/issues/38).